# I can't perform a request from ReactJS. The header can not be written correctly

Tags: reactjs, spring, security, spring-security, axios

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/omp/patients', { headers: {authorization: 'Bearer ' + token}})
        .then( response => {
                this.state = response.data;
            }
        ).catch(ex=> {
            alert("You are not registered");
            //console.log(e)
        });
```

[image]

In network I have the field: "Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization" but no field "authorization: token"

Comment: It looks correct, you could try ```{ headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` }}```

Comment: Don't work! "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/omp/patients' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the Authorization header correctly, as in the comment above.

For your reply about CORS Policy:

You will need to learn about CORS, but essentially Chrome and other browsers halt network requests if they do not have proper CORS headers set upon response. A preflight is an initial request that is sent to the same URL to learn whether the URL will support CORS, before sending the actual request. It looks like the server doesn't understand CORS preflights or isn't configured properly.

You have a couple options:

1. If you have access to the server configuration or code (such as a Laravel or NodeJS server), install a CORS plugin.
2. If you are the only user using this, you can install CORS browser extensions for Chrome or Firefox or whatever.

Comment: I have access to the server. It is written by me in Java. ThankYou. I would try to solve this!

Comment: Excellent. I haven't worked with Java servers in a while but I imagine there are numerous articles and guides for enabling CORS support in your server.

Comment: The error is because the Server thrown an exception. In the server I try to get the token from the authorization field. If the header "Authorization" is missing the exception is thrown. To check this I hardcoded the token in that method.

Comment: ```   public Authentication attemptAuthentication(... httpServletRequest, ... httpServletResponse) throws AuthenticationException {


        String header = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");

        if(header == null || !header.startsWith("authorization")){
            //here i hardcoded token
        
            throw new RuntimeException("JWT Token is missing");
        }

        String authenticationToken = header.substring(13);
      
        return  getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
    }```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/omp/patients', { headers: { "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token}})
        .then( response => {
                this.state = response.data;
            }
        ).catch(ex=> {
            alert("You are not registered");
            //console.log(e)
        });
```

Also in you app.js/index.js where ever you are running your server import/require cors module and do like this:

```
let cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Hope this helps!